# ASP.NET ODataController Not Receiving Property values

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, odata

I'm working on an app that uses an AngularJS front-end with an ASP.NET backend based on oData. I'm having some difficulties getting post requests to work. The post methods in my controllers all basically look like this:

```
 Function Post(ByVal eDI_CUSTOMER As EDI_CUSTOMER) As IHttpActionResult
        If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
            Return BadRequest(ModelState)
        End If

        db.EDI_CUSTOMER.Add(eDI_CUSTOMER)

        Try
            db.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As DbUpdateException
            If (EDI_CUSTOMERExists(eDI_CUSTOMER.ID)) Then
                Return Conflict()
            Else
                Throw
            End If
        End Try

        Return Created(eDI_CUSTOMER)
    End Function
```

When I try to issue a post request I can see in the Chrome debugger that the data is passed as expected. If I use a content type of "application/json" nothing is received by the .NET controller. If I use a content type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" an object with the expected properties is received, but all of the property values are blank.

Does anyone know what I'm missing?

I'm using oData 4.

Comment: I'm a C# programmer so this is just a shot in the dark: What happens if you change `ByVal` to `ByRef`?

Comment: This may be many things, could you provide us a javascript sample and the EDI_CUSTOMER Interface ?do you use CORS ?

Comment: Thanks Rogerio. I don't think all that is necessary. I can verify that the post is being sent and I know the objects are received by .NET. It turns out this is a pretty common issue with ASP.NET & Angular in general. The answer I posted below resolves this issue, however; it breaks all of my patch requests. I'll just have to figure out how to only use  $httpParamSerializerJQLike for posts and I should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding code to use JQuery like serialization to my run block like below:

```
.run(function($http, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
        $http.defaults.transformRequest.unshift($httpParamSerializerJQLike);
})
```

resolved this issue for me.